# Conditional apex query

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to return an SOQL query based on a conditional statement.
my code looks the following:

```
string FullQuery = '';
if(selectedRegion == 'All'){
            FullQuery = 'select id, name, Region__r.Id, Region__r.Name, CreatedDate from Country__c where Id in (select country_link__c from Market__c where Focus_Year__c = True)';
} else {
            FullQuery = 'select id, name, Region__r.Id, Region__r.Name, CreatedDate from Country__c where Id in (select country_link__c from Market__c where Focus_Year__c = True) and Region__r.Id == :selectedRegion';
        }
List<Country__c> RelevantCountryList2 = Database.query(FullQuery);
system.debug(RelevantCountryList2);
```

When I do that I get an error :  FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: unexpected token: '=='

any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of second query in which you are using   **==**

```
FullQuery = 'select id, name, Region__r.Id, Region__r.Name, CreatedDate from Country__c where Id in (select country_link__c from Market__c where Focus_Year__c = True) and Region__r.Id == :selectedRegion';
```

instead of this use single =

```
FullQuery = 'select id, name, Region__r.Id, Region__r.Name, CreatedDate from Country__c where Id in (select country_link__c from Market__c where Focus_Year__c = True) and Region__r.Id = :selectedRegion';
```

Thanks